# Cause of "Browser needs to be launched with the global proxy" Playwright error

Tags: http-proxy, playwright

I'm running a Playwright test that makes a request to `http://localhost:3000/somePage` and wanted to run the request through a proxy (the Fiddler proxy, so I can inspect the traffic, but that's beside the point).

In my `playwright.config.ts` I have:

```
projects: [
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: {
        ...devices['Desktop Chrome'],
        proxy: {
          server: 'http://127.0.0.1:8888'
        }
      },
    },
]
```

The `proxy` key is what I added to what was already in the config file generated by Playwright when I set up the project.

When I run my test, I get the following error and the test fails to run:

```
browser.newContext: Browser needs to be launched with the global proxy. If all contexts override the proxy, global proxy will be never used and can be any string, for example "launch({ proxy: { server: 'http://per-context' } })"
```

A search online turns up little other than a couple github issues that were closed a long time ago.  It seems like it's complaining that it *should* use the proxy, but only... when I tell it to use the proxy.

When I remove the proxy from the config, the test runs just fine.  What am I missing?

Comment: Same problem we face now. We can't run our test in a build machine that requires a proxy. Have you found a workaround?

Comment: No, haven't revisited it since posting.  Sorry :(  If it's enough of an issue, you could do a minimal repro and open a github issue and see if it gets some attention.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by ducking the issue: I used firefox instead.

```
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Window...../537.36'
browser = await p.firefox.launch()
context = await browser.new_context(user_agent=user_agent, proxy={
            "server": "1xx.xxx.xx.xxx:3xxx"
        })
page = await context.new_page()
```